# How to return object of first and last names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

The result is returning {firstname: 'Mike,Henry,Pete', lastname: 'Port,Split,Micky'}
I want result to return
{
firstName: Mike,
lastName: Port
},
{
firstName: Henry,
lastName: Split
},
{
firstName: Pete,
lastName: Micky
}

```
var data = "Mike Port, Henry Split, Pete Micky";
var firstName = [];
var lastName = [];
var result = [];
var newNames = data.replaceAll(", ", ",");
var fullName = newNames.split(',');
fullName.forEach(name => {
  let splitted = name.split(" ");
  firstName.push(splitted[0]);
  lastName.push(splitted[1]);
});

f_name_list = firstName.toString().split(", ");
l_name_list = lastName.toString().split(", ");

for (let i = 0; i < f_name_list.length; i++) {
  result.push({ 
    firstname: f_name_list[i],
    lastname: l_name_list[i]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you’re looking for the inverse of this, see [how to display complete array?](/q/39201953/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split data with `", "` then split with `" "`

```js
var data = "Mike Port, Henry Split, Pete Micky";
var result = [];
var newNames = data.split(", ");
newNames.forEach(name => {
  let splitted = name.split(" ");
  result.push({ 
    firstname:splitted[0],
    lastname: splitted[1]
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in one line combining [String#split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const data = 'Mike Port, Henry Split, Pete Micky'
const result = data
  .split(', ')
  .map(s => s.split(' '))
  .map(([firstname, lastname]) => ({ firstname, lastname }))
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the long-term it maybe better to not specify the keys in the code. What if you were to add a new property called `age` to the data? That would mean having to go into into the code and update it to accommodate the change which is a hassle.

This example removes that complication by keeping a track of the keys, and looping over them, and the values, to create a new dataset. No hard-coding of the keys anywhere.

```js
const data = {
  firstname: 'Mike,Henry,Pete',
  lastname: 'Port,Split,Micky',
  age: '10,100,20',
  location: 'France,Germany,Iceland',
  role: 'chef,musician,writer',
  tree: 'larch,maple,oak'
};

// Get the keys and values from the object
const keys = Object.keys(data);
const values = Object.values(data).map(str => str.split(','));

// Temporary array
const out = [];

// Loop over the first array in the values array
for (let i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {

  // Initialise an empty object
  // for each nested array
  const obj = {};
  
  // Loop over the keys, create a new object with
  // that key, and the element of the nested value array
  // and merge it with the object
  for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    const prop = { [keys[j]]: values[j][i] };
    Object.assign(obj, prop);
  }

  // Push the object to the array
  out.push(obj);

}

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys)
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: the only thing I noticed is that if I add an additional keyname such as "location" then it outputs an addition object with undefined values - {firstname: undefined, lastname: undefined, age: undefined, location: undefined} which I can correct by adding const const valueLength = values[0].length; and changing values.length in the for to for (let i = 0; i < valueLength; i++) but not sure if this is ideal (to add valueLength)

Comment: @Brian I was calculating the `i` index incorrectly. I've now fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```js
var data = "Mike Port, Henry Split, Pete Micky";

function parseData(data){
  data = data.split(', ')
  let arr = []
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    arr.push({firstName:data[i].split(' ')[0].replace(',',''),lastName:data[i].split(' ')[1]})
  }
  return arr
}
console.log(parseData(data))
```